# Java project build jar and depenedencies

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to create an executable from a Java project in eclipse. I understand that the first step would be creating a JAR file so after searching the site I was able to compile the following Ant build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configuration of the Ant build system to generate a Jar file --> 
<project name="GraphBuild" default="CreateJar">
  <target name="CreateJar" description="Create Jar file">
     <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="GraphEditor" />
     </manifest>
     <jar jarfile="GraphEditor.jar" basedir="." includes="*.class" 
          manifest="MANIFEST.MF" />
  </target>
</project>
```

When I run the GraphEditor.jar using the following command

```
java -jar GraphEditor.jar
```

I receive `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` because I have some referenced libraries in my project and it seems that the loader is not able to find them. I tried setting the -cp variable with no luck.

Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

With maven you can easily create an executable jar with all dependencies. 
Maybe you want to use maven instead of ant.
[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the dependent jars appropriately and point to directory of your `class` files correctly.

Something like:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${class.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}/lib1.jar ${lib.dir}/lib2.jar"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the Class-Path variable with the dependent jar files with appropriate location and try?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question properly I would first like to say you cannot use the -cp and -jar.  If you declare a classpath when creating the jar (in ant @see http://www.tomred.net/tomred-java-jar-meta-inf-manifest.html) for example so that it is in the MANIFEST then you need not include the -cp.

If you want to test your jar with a classpath you should do as you have but swap the -jar for -cp as below.

```
java -cp lib/;deps/;GraphEditor.jar org.package.to.RunClass
```

Simply -jar and -cp are multiply exclusive.  Note: ";" separation in windows ":" in linux